# boto3 cloudwatch error with sequenceToken

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a script who runs in a EC2 envery minutes with a cron job and it sends logs in cloudwatch. My problem is that it sends a lot of logs in a short time and sometime create an error (An error occurred (InvalidSequenceTokenException) when calling the PutLogEvents operation).

I read that it's possible to send 5 logs by second by stream log. And sometime I send more.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_PutLogEvents.html

I'm using a python class :

```
def sequencetoken(self):
    logdescribe = self.client.describe_log_streams(logGroupName=self.group, logStreamNamePrefix=self.stream)
    logStreams = logdescribe['logStreams']
    logStream = logStreams[0]
    sequenceToken = logStream['uploadSequenceToken']
    return sequenceToken


def send_cloudwatch_log_message(self, message=None):
    response = self.client.put_log_events(
        logGroupName=self.group,
        logStreamName=self.stream,
        sequenceToken=self.sequencetoken(),  # IMPORTANT -> if it's your first log you don't need sequencetoken()
        logEvents=[
            {
                'timestamp': self.get_time(),
                'message': 'SID= {} JOB_ID= {} INFO= {} ST={}'.format(self.session, self.job_id, message, self.sequencetoken())
            }
        ]
    )
```

I think maybe put a time.sleep(0.1) or create a buffer but I'm not sure that it's a good solution.

Somebody had the same error ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to utilize batching:

> The maximum batch size is 1,048,576 bytes, and this size is calculated
>   as the sum of all event messages in UTF-8, plus 26 bytes for each log
>   event.

And:

> The maximum number of log events in a batch is 10,000.

So you can add further events into `logEvents` array until you run out of byte size limit or exceed 10000 entries. Sending one batch counts as a single request towards 5 req/sec throttling limit.

Comment: I think my error is because put_log_event is called several time in a short time and my function give 1 sequencetoken for 2 logs. That's why there is an error. I did a try except by getting the nextToken and resend put_log_event. Currently it works.

Comment: @LaurentCesaro while it will solve the problem in short term, you still might experience throttling if log volume grows. On top of that sending each event separately consumes more network I/O time and decreases overall performance of app compared to doing 1 API call with a big batch. So I advise to try it regardless